# JSONP cross-domain request with Ajax issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to use IPInfoDB to obtain the IP geolocation in an application but I'm having issues that I can't resolve. I created a HTML file and did the very basic requirements to get the info from IPInfoDB and it works fine. When I try to run the exact same code inside the application it gives the error "Failed to load resource" in the console on the first attempt and then any attempts after that throw a GET error pointing to the jquery file on line 8516 (developer version of jquery-1.10.2.js). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code that works perfectly in the html file but throws an error when inside the application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.IPinfoTableDiv
{
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
}
.IPinfoTable
{
    width:100%;
}
table thead tr td, table tbody tr td
{
    border: solid 1px lightgrey;
}
</style>

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
var geoLocationUrl = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=MyKey&format=json';

$(document).ready(function() 
{
function handleData(data)
{
    var newTR = $("<tr/>")
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.cityName))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.countryCode))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.countryName))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.ipAddress))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.latitude))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.longitude))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.regionName))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.timeZone))
    .append($('<td/>').text(data.zipCode));

    $("#IPInfoBody").append(newTR);
}

jQuery.ajax(
{
    type : 'GET',
    url : geoLocationUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    success : function(data)
    {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
        handleData(data);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="IPinfoTableDiv">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Country Code</td>
            <td>Country Name</td>
            <td>IP Address</td>
            <td>Latitude</td>
            <td>Longitude</td>
            <td>Region</td>
            <td>Time Zone</td>
            <td>Zipcode</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="IPInfoBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed the first time I attempt to load the page in the application and it throws the "Failed to load resources" it gives a link, which, when opened brings up the JSON that I want to use. Attached are images to show what i'm talking about.

Initial Failure with link:
[image: InitialFailure]

Clicking the link brings up the JSON that I want:
[image: JSON link]

GET error pointing at jquery file line 8516 if I attempt more than once:
[image]

I am reading up on JSONP and am having trouble understanding it. I read something about it returns the data wrapped in a function, which is what I'm assuming is what is in the link in the second picture. I am not sure why the normal HTML page works fine but the application fails to load the resource on the initial attempt and then just has a GET error that points to jQuery. The application is in an eclipse environment using tomcat to serve it.

UPDATE: In Firefox, it works fine (in the application as well). In Google Chrome, not so much. I'll look into that more and see if I can determine why that is and update accordingly.

UPDATE 2: So I've tested in Firefox and IE(10) and both of those have no issues. It seems to be specific to Chrome. Even using the jsfiddle that Kevin B posted, the issue only occurs in chrome.

Comment: I would code it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2naUG/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/2jhWY/ Note, `crossDomain: true` is almost never needed.

Comment: what does `fails inside the application` mean?

Comment: @KevinB what do you mean "works for you" your fiddle gives invalid api key and you are using 10.1

Comment: When I put the html file inside the application and it attempts to load it, I get those pictures that are above. "Failed to load resource" on first attempt and GET errors pointing at the jquery.js file as shown above.

Comment: @mplungjan of course it gives an invalid key, i used an invalid key. but it's successfull, that means the api supports jsonp and the request to the api is syntactically correct.

Comment: And here it is still working with the latest version of the 1.x branch: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/2jhWY/1/

Comment: @KevinB When i attempt to run your fiddle it just throws the same GET error but points to line 8534 (due to version differences in the jquery file, but it is the same point as the 1.10.2 js file).

Comment: Which is this line:

head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );

Comment: what browser/version?

Comment: Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the AdBlock Plus extension blocking the JSONP from loading for some reason. Once I disabled AdBlock Plus, everything works fine in Chrome.